# how to use os.startfile() in Android environment?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I have an Android Python 3 kivy application and I'm trying to start the calendar from my app, but I don't know how to use `os.startfile()` in an Android environment. I know how to use in the Windows environment, but Android is different.

EDIT:
finally I found a way to make it work with Kivy and jnius to start any Android application from Python 3 
just put the name of package at `app_to_launch =`
thanks to static_cast who point me the way

```
from jnius import cast
from jnius import autoclass
from kivy.context import get_current_context

app_to_launch = "org.package.name"
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
activity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
pm = activity.getPackageManager()
app_intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app_to_launch)
activity.startActivity(app_intent)
```

Comment: You want to start an Android calendar application? You can do that using the pyjnius module and an Android intent.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! i read the documentations for pyjnius module and Android intent.